# FileNotFoundError while training deep learning model created with the help of Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, image-classification

I am working on a deep learning project that predicts the disease a tomato leaf has on it. I am using VGG16 pre-trained model for this.

Now, during the training process, after first epoch, my model is throwing this error:

```
Epoch 1/10
625/625 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.9151 - accuracy: 0.6993
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[21], line 1
----> 1 model.fit(train_image_gen, validation_data=test_image_gen, epochs=10)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tomato_dataset\\test\\Tomato___Spider_mites Two-spotted_spider_mite\\1bbcbd22-5959-4ae4-a044-85f81a1a02dd___Com.G_SpM_FL_9319.JPG_3bebcbb8-4297-4946-95a2-961b3c45f723.JPG'
```

[image: filenotfounderroronepicone]

[image: filenotfounderroronepicone]

Now, i am unable to figure out why tensorflow is throwing me this error although I have this file present inside the folder

[image: filepath]

I initially removed all the blank spaces and words that were present in the filenames using a python script, but that did not solve the problem at all.

I am using Tensorflow version: 2.10.0, keras version: 2.10.0 and python version: 3.9.7